# Seeing two python scripts side by side

Tags: comparison

I would like to have two python scripts (i.e., with a `.py` extension) side-by-side on screen for my visual image to see differences and similarities in them. I wonder how I can do this easily.

Comment: By opening two windows and align them side-by-side ?

Comment: What platform are you running?

Comment: I would like a program which I may be able to run through, automatically picking out those things which are similar or not.

Comment: Search for `diff` or `visual diff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "*diff*", "*visual diff*" or "*compare tool*" or something like that.

You can use [`diff`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) or [`colordiff`](http://www.colordiff.org) Linux command-line tools, or if you want something with GUI, you can try for example [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) or [KDiff3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/).

But I would advice you to search and try some diff tools yourself and pick the one which fits your needs the best.

BTW it has nothing to do with Python, it works with any text file. But some  of diff tools has a syntax highlighting, which is useful if you're comparing a source code.